# How to find tie game python

Tags: python

Hi i was making this tic tac toe game and i watched some tutorials for it, but there wasn't any game that could end with tie game i tried to make one but the game freezes when tie game appears don't worry about my Finnish variables and comments

```
import random

board = [0,1,2,
3,4,5,
6,7,8]

def show():
    print board[0], '|',board[1],'|',board[2]
    print '----------'
    print board[3], '|',board[4],'|',board[5]
    print '----------'
    print board[6], '|',board[7],'|',board[8]

def checkLine(char, spot1, spot2, spot3):
    if (board[spot1] == char) and (board[spot2] == char) and (board [spot3] == char)    :
        return True
    else:
        return False

def checkAll(char):
    ret = False
    if checkLine(char, 0, 1, 2):
        ret = True
    if checkLine(char, 0,3, 6):
        ret = True
    if checkLine(char, 1, 4, 7):
        ret = True
    if checkLine(char, 2, 5, 8):
        ret = True
    if checkLine(char, 6, 7, 8):
        ret = True
    if checkLine(char, 3, 4, 5):
        ret = True
    if checkLine(char, 2, 4, 6):
        ret = True
    if checkLine(char, 0, 4, 8):
        ret = True
    return ret

moves = range(9) 
numindex = 1
ratkennut = False
while moves:
    show()

    input = raw_input("Put x: ")
    try:
        val = int(input)
        input = int(input)
    except ValueError:
        print("Input number!")
        input = raw_input("Put x: ")
        input = int(input)
    if input in moves:
        moves.remove(input)

    if board [input] != 'x' and board[input] != 'o':
        board[input] = 'x'

        if checkAll('x') == True:
            print "~~ X Won ~~"
            ratkennut = True
            break;

        while moves:
            random.seed() #Gives opponents move
            opponent = random.choice(moves)
            moves.remove(opponent)

            if board[opponent] != 'o' and board[opponent] != 'x':
                board[opponent] = 'o'

                if checkAll('o') == True:
                    print "~~ O Won ~~"
                    ratkennut = True
                break;
    else:
        print 'This  spot is taken'
else:
    print "Tie!"
```

Question: What's wrong with this code when the game ends with tie game it freezes and i need to ctrl + c how to make it find the tie game and print "tie game"
I edited it and now it works really great!

Comment: Any question for us ?

Comment: Edited it. read again

Comment: "don't worry about my Finnish variables" lol, really? Seems very helpful to me, that you expect the `print"Tasapeli"` statement to run when it's a tie game, but by obfuscating your code with non english names&strings you're not helping anyone in helping you. Don't know what a `ratkennut` is, but don't you need to check `numindex` against `9` instead of `6`?

Comment: Also, output can be in Finnish (or w/e language that is), that's fine. But variable names should not be. It's considered good practice to write variable names in English, not only for your learning curve but for anyone looking at your code in the future (like now) :)

Comment: To put it another way: the SO community, including those who don't speak English as their first language, is composed of programmers working at least partly in English. So the norm *for them* is to code in English, and it will certainly help them if you work in English when you reduce your code to a minimal example that demonstrates your problem. The norm for other groups of programmers may be to do things differently, but you won't hear much from those groups on the English SO.

Answer (score 2):

Your `randint` move choice in a `while` loop for the opponent could run indefinitely, especially as the number of valid moves remaining gets smaller. Instead, make a list of valid moves and `list.remove()` each move from it:

```
moves = range(9)
```

This simplifies the user's move:

```
if input in moves:
    moves.remove(input)
```

The opponent's move:

```
opponent = random.choice(moves)
moves.remove(opponent)
```

And determining the end of the game:

```
while moves:
    ...
else:
    print "It's a tie."
```

Answer (score 1):

You could count your moves there are only 9 moves in a tic tac toe game.

You want something like:

```
if  not checkAll('o') and  not checkAll('x') and moves == 9:
    print "Tie Game"
    break
```